# I got a C++ cygwin_exception and a stacktrace but I don't know what is going on

Tags: c++, cygwin

I tried to test my `Data` class which is supposed to read, write and print a 2d vector map.

`Data.h`:

```
/* 
 * File:   Data.h
 * Author: Kevin
 *
 * Created on 04 October 2015, 19:54
 */

#ifndef DATA_H
#define DATA_H
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Data {

public:
    Data();
    void readMap();
    void writeMap();
    void writePlayerData();
    void readPlayerData();
    void printMap();
private:
    ifstream _input;
    ofstream _output;
    unsigned _ySize;
    unsigned _xSize;
    vector<vector<char> > map;
};

#endif  /* DATA_H */
```

`Data.cpp`:

```
/*
* File:   Data.cpp
* Author: Kevin
*
* Created on 04 October 2015, 19:54
*/
#include <iostream>
#include "Data.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::getline;

Data::Data() {
    _ySize = 0;
    _xSize = 0;
}

void Data::writeMap() {
    _output.open("map.txt");
    _output << "Test" << endl;
    _output.close();
}

void Data::readMap() {
    string const fileName = "map.txt";
    string line;
    _input.open("map.txt");
    if (_input.fail()) {
        perror("map.txt");
    }
    unsigned y = 0;
    while (getline(_input, line)) {
        line = line.c_str();
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            map[y][i] = line[i];
        }
    }
}

void Data::printMap() {
    cout << "Printing Map... \n" << map.size() << "\n" << endl;
    for (int y = 0; y < _ySize; y++) {
        cout << map.size() << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < _xSize; x++) {
            cout << map[y].size() << endl;
        cout << map[y][x] << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Using this main function:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Data.h"

int main() {
  Data dataTest;
  //dataTest.writeMap();
  dataTest.readMap();
  //dataTest.printMap();
 }
```

And I got this error message (I'm using netbeans):

```
2 [main] roguelike 9280 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to roguelike.exe.stackdump

RUN FAILED (exit value 35,584, total time: 1s)
```

And in the file that contains the stacktrace is this:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=001004024C0 rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000 rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=00000006000283D0 rdi=0000000000000000 r8
=000000000000000A r9 =8080808080808080 r10=FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFF r11=0000000600042708 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000001 r14=000000000024CB63 r15=000000000024CB63 rbp=000000000024C5F0 rsp=000000000024C5F0 program=C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Dev\Roguelike\dist\Debug\Cygwin_4.x-Windows\roguelike.exe, pid 9280, thread main cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B Stack trace: Frame        Function    Args 0000024C5F0  001004024C0 (00000000000, 006000283D0, 00000000000, 00600042708) 0000024C680  001004012D6 (00000000001, 001802E3A40, 00000000000, 003FF0AB258) 0000024C6F0  001004016CE (00000000020, FF0700010302FF00, 0018004830F, 0000024D680) 0000024CBC0  00180048380 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000) 00000000000  0018004607C (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000) 00000000000  00180046114 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000) 00000000000  001004018B1 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000) 00000000000  00100401010 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00100401000) 00000000000  7FFD5D852D92 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000) 00000000000  7FFD5F7D9F64 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000) End of stack trace
```

And I really can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: In the header file, i'll include the code for that as well

Comment: You're accessing (or trying to access, anyway) elements in `map` without having initialise those elements. Hence the error. You can't just `map[y][i] =  ...` without having initialised `map[y]` to at least `i` + 1 elements, which in turn requires having initialised `map` to at least `y` + 1 elements.

Comment: `map[y][i] = line[i];` you can't do this on unsized vectors. Use `resize()` before accessing indices, or fill in data using `push_back()`.

Comment: `line = line.c_str();` -- I winced. *Why would you do that?*

Comment: Becaus i thought(im not sure if im right) that a cstring is a vector of chars, and thus would fit into my vector<vector <char> > map variable

Comment: A vector of vectors called "map"!? Why don't you use a, um, map?

Comment: _"Becaus i thought(im not sure if im right) that a cstring is a vector of chars"_ Where did you hear that?

Comment: _"and thus would fit into my vector<vector <char> > map variable"_ Even if that were true, you were trying to assign it back into `line`, not into the "map".